# Term for positive only basis

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I'm trying to figure out properties and identify sets of vectors that make what I term a 'positive basis'. Optimally I would like to know if someone else has already did math with similar concepts so just knowing the right term for something like this would be an optimal answer.

How I define the term 'positive basis' is similar to a basis in linear algebra. A linear algebra basis requires linear independence and spanning. My 'positive basis' requires a spanning property but I haven't formulated a linear independence property. For 'positive basis' $P$ of a vector space $V$ if and only if:

For every vector $v$ in $V$, one can choose $a_1,...,a_n$ such that $\forall_x: a_x>=0$ and $v_1,...,v_n$ in $B$ such that $v = a_1\cdot v_1 + ... + a_n\cdot v_n$

Comment: If $b$ is the first vector in your positive basis how would you write $-b$ in the form you require?

Comment: It would have to be a combination of other basis vectors. In 2d space you would need 3 vectors. One example positive basis would be <1,0>, <0,1>, and <-.5,-.5>. You can write -<1,0> as = 2*<-.5,-.5>+1*<0,1>, etc.etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of $n+1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a positive basis (in your sense) if and only if the origin is in the interior of their convex hull $S$ (which will be a simplex). That's equivalent to the existence of a unique way to write $0$ as a linear combination with positive coefficients.

The independence term you want is  [affine independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space).

Each point in the interior of $S$ is a unique convex combination of the vectors. The points on the boundary of $S$ are unique convex combinations with some coefficients $0$. To express any other vector $v$, see where the ray in that direction from the origin crosses a hyperplane $H$ that bounds $S$. Then $v$ will be a nonnegative linear combination of the vertices of $S$ on $H$. It will be a positive linear combination of those vertices as long as the point where the ray crosses $H$ is in the interior of that face of $S$.

In general, if $B$ is an affinely independent set of $n+1$ points then any vector is a unique linear combination of elements of $B$ with coefficients summing to $0$, so an affine basis. It's a positive basis if the combination for $0$ has all positive coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

I got this: take a basis. Construct the positive cone, which is convex; it is the convex hull  of the rays defined by the basis vectors.   Take any vector $u$ in the interior,  that is all coefficients are strictly positive.   Add $-u$  to the original basis and you have your set.